# Easy example of $Ax =b$ floating point arithmetic.

Tags: numerical-methods, approximation, floating-point

Solve $Ax =b$ with two-digit floating-point arithmetic.

We have $$ A=
  \begin{pmatrix}
    1 & 1\\
    1 & 0,99\\
 \end{pmatrix}
$$ and

$$ b =  
  \begin{pmatrix}
    -1 \\
     1 \\
  \end{pmatrix}
$$

So I get : $$ \left[
\begin{array}{cc|c}
  1&1&-1\\
  0&1\cdot10^{-2}&2
\end{array}
\right] $$

for $x$ I got $$ x=\begin{pmatrix}
    199 \\
     -200 \\
  \end{pmatrix} $$ but the solution says that $$ x=\begin{pmatrix}
    -200 \\
     200 \\
  \end{pmatrix} $$ is correct, but why? Remark: it seems so that the solution has a mistake. it should be (200,-200)

I know that this question could be very easy for a lot of people. I am a complete amateur in terms of floating point arithmetic.

Answer (score 3):

The problem **said** that you were working in "two digit floating point arithmetic". "-199" rounded to two digits is "-200".

Comment: Oh! so that means two digit floating point arithmetic. Sorry this term is completely new for me. So we get $-199$, which should be $199$ by the way. Sorry for my mistake. Now we write $199 = 0.199 * 10^3$ which is round to $0.2 *10^3$, right? I am just asking to really understand floating point arithmetic.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you tried doing it by inverting $A$.  Since $A$ is nearly singular (the determinant is $0.01$, while the average entry is about $1$), there is a high risk of numerical instability (floating point errors becoming larger than approximation errors).

So, let's try solving your system by Gaussian elimination:
$$
\left.
\begin{array}{rrrrr}
x_{1} & + &  x_{2} & = & -1\\
x_{1} & + &  0.99 x_{2} & = & 1\\
\end{array}
\right\}
\Rightarrow
\left\{
\begin{array}{rrrrr}
x_{1} & + &  x_{2} & = & -1\\
 &  &  -0.01 x_{2} & = & 2\\
\end{array}\right\}
$$
The last equation gives us $x_{2} = -200$, so $x_{1} = 199$.  This calculation differs from yours only by a minus sign, and differs principally from the other answer you cite from your source.

Comment: Oh! Thank you. Of course I made a mistake and forgot the minus sign :D. Indeed $x_2$ is $-200$. but we have to round $x_1$, I think.